# mySQL Order By placeholders

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am attempting to call a Stored Procedure to return a set of results Ordered in a specific order (order by), here is my Stored Procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getReadReportsPagingFinal`(startIndex INTEGER, pageSize INTEGER, sortingCol VARCHAR(255), sortingDir VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

    SET @Query = "SELECT * FROM reports 
    WHERE 'new'=0
    ORDER BY ?, ?
    LIMIT ?, ?";


    SET @a = sortingCol;
    SET @b = sortingDir;
    SET @c = startIndex;
    SET @d = pageSize;

    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @Query;
    EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a, @b, @c, @d;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END
```

I understand placeholders cannot be used for column names:

> With most drivers, placeholders can't be used for any element of a
>   statement that would prevent the database server from validating the
>   statement and creating a query execution plan for it.

So I attempted to concatenate sortingCol and sortingDir to the query:

```
@Query = CONCAT(@Query, sortingCol);
```

which gave a syntax error.

Is there a better way to do this?  Currently parameters are passed via a PHP script which calls the Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put the column at the end after the LIMIT clause. The column you sort by must be in the ORDER BY clause. But you're right, you can't use a parameter for column names.

```
SET @Query = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM reports 
  WHERE 'new'=0
  ORDER BY ", sortingCol, " ", sortingDir,
" LIMIT ?, ?");
```

Be careful to put spaces around SQL keywords in these string fragments. You wouldn't want to end up with `ORDER BY column1 ASCLIMIT ? ?`.

Also keep in mind that you are at risk of SQL injection by interpolating procedure arguments into your query before you PREPARE it. What if someone tricks your application into passing a sortingCol: `1 UNION SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns --`

You need to take measures to *whitelist* these strings before concatenating them into your SQL. That's the best defense against SQL injection vulnerabilities when you're handling dynamic column names or SQL keywords.

Comment: Do I escape the string passed in before preparing?  Or are those two separate injection prevention methods.  I will read more about it.

Comment: You can't escape the `sortingDir` because SQL keywords are not quoted. And there is no appropriate function to do the right kind of escaping for column names. It's better to whitelist them.

Comment: this isn't a 6 character or more edit so I cannot suggest an edit but there is a _tiny_ syntax error after the last double quote before the semicolon. Need a closing parentheses. `LIMIT ?, ?");`